# How does Ruby's #count method deal with nil values?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing Ruby exercises for the Odin Project (programming newcomer), and we're tasked with recreating Ruby's #count method. Given an array like:

```
nil_list = [false, false, nil]
```

Observations:

- nil_list.count == 3, its length.
- nil_list.count(nil) == 1, the number of times nil is present in the list.
- nil_list given a block behaves as expected.

When I try to recreate it, here's what I come up with:

```
module Enumerable
  def my_count (find = nil)
    result = 0
    for i in self
      if block_given?
        result += 1 if yield(i)
      elsif find != nil
        result += 1 if i == find
      else return self.length
      end
    end
    return result
  end
end
```

The problem here is that this doesn't actually count nils if we enter nil in as an argument, since this is the same (according to my code) as there not being an argument.

ie, nil_list.my_count(nil) == 3 instead of 1.

While typing this question I had a slightly different idea:

```
module Enumerable
  def my_count (find = "")
    result = 0
    for i in self
      if block_given?
        result += 1 if yield(i)
      elsif find != ""
        result += 1 if i == find
      else return self.length
      end
    end
    return result
  end
end
```

So this fixes the problem I was having with searches for nil, but now nil_list.count("") == 0 whereas nil_list.my_count("") == 3. Same issue, just relocated to "" which I assume doesn't ever get used.

At this point I'm just curious: how does the actual count method prevent this issue from happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can write `def my_count(*args)` and check then length of `args`. I'd write:

```
module Enumerable
  def my_count(*args)
    case
    when args.size > 1
      raise ArgumentError
    when args.size == 1
      value = args.first
      reduce(0) { |acc, x| value == x ? acc + 1 : acc }
    when block_given?
      reduce(0) { |acc, x| yield(x) ? acc + 1 : acc }
    else
      reduce(0) { |acc, x| acc + 1 }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice! You might want to return an `ArgumentError` if `args.size > 1`. An alternative to `reduce` is, for example, `select { |e| e == value }.size`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I was thinking how to do the Argument, looks ok. The problem with select + size is that it creates an intermediate array, I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: On an ideal world, and using modern Rubies: `lazy.select { |x| x == value }.size`, but Enumerable::Lazy has no `size`.

Comment: You could replace `reduce(0) { |acc, x| acc + 1 }` with `size` (no intermediate array!).

Comment: @Cary, `size` is an Array method, not Enumerable. So we should check first the class.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking of Ruby's classes that include Enumerable, most of which have `size`, but it wouldn't work for a custom class that included Enumerable if size was not defined. Should anyone else be interested, these are the built-in class (in v.2.1) that `include Enumerable` and don't have `size`: `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c.included_modules.include?(Enumerable) && !c.instance_methods.include?(:size) }
=> [C, Enumerator::Generator, Dir, ARGF.class, IO, A]`.  Thinking through this has been helpful to me.

Comment: I have read source of `count` from a Ruby 1.9.3. Your approach is very similar!

Comment: Thanks everyone! I hadn't thought to check the length of args-- that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The ugly truth is: in most Ruby implementations, `Enumerable#count` isn't actually written in Ruby. In MRI, YARV and MRuby, it's written in C, in JRuby and XRuby, it's written in Java, in IronRuby and Ruby.NET, it's written in C#, in MacRuby, it's written in Objective-C, in MagLev, it's written in Smalltalk, in Topaz, it's written in RPython, in Cardinal, it's written in PIR or PASM, and so on. And it not only is not written in Ruby, it's also got privileged access to the internals of the execution engine, in particular, it can access the arguments that were passed, which you cannot do from Ruby.

Such overloaded methods appear all over the core library and standard library, but they can't easily be written in Ruby. The implementers cheat by either writing them in languages that *do* support overloading (e.g. C# or Java), or they give them privileged access to the internals of the execution engine.

The standard workaround in Ruby is to (ab)use the fact that the default value of an optional parameter is just a normal Ruby expression and that local variables in a default value expression are visible inside the method body:

```
def my_count(find = (find_passed = false; nil))
  if find_passed # find was passed
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

A second possibility is to use some unforgeable unique token as the default value:

```
undefined = Object.new
define_method(:my_count) do |find = undefined|
  if undefined.equal?(find) # find was not passed
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```